# My song of india plant have these light brown spots. What are they?

Tags: diseases

These brown spots are worring me please tell me are they natural or a symptom of a disease. They are just printed on the leaves.!

Comment: These numerous light brown spots variable in size and shape, present along the broad green pitch of the dracena leaf

Comment: Can you upload a photograph of the plant please